# Определить оптимальный тип мапинга

Tags: hibernate, java, mysql

Есть [БД](http://dbdsgnr.appspot.com/app#agdkYmRzZ25ycg4LEgZTY2hlbWEY8b14DA)
Погогите определить тип обединения таблиц для мапинга в hibernate (one-to-one, many-to-many, many-to-one, one-to-many).
Так-же буду рад ссылкам на понятные статьи для определенного типа соединения.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот пожайлуйста) http://viralpatel.net/blogs/hibernate-one-to-many-xml-mapping-tutorial/
А тип маппинга будет зависеть от структеры Вашей модели)

Comment: очень благодарен.

Answer (score 0):

Всё зависит от структуры твоей базы данных и от зависимостей таблиц друг к другу, если б ты рассказал, что конкретно тебе нужно то получил бы чёткий ответ, а так читай: 
1) http://habrahabr.ru/post/29694/
2) http://javatutor.net/articles/hibernate-many-to-many-one-to-one

Comment: Вот бд http://dbdsgnr.appspot.com/app#agdkYmRzZ25ycg4LEgZTY2hlbWEY8b14DA
Мне нужно выбрать таблицу телефон, а вместе с ней со связаных таблиц, описание.